# Creating a zip file containing Text Files

Tags: java, zip

I've been trying to tackle this problem for a day or two and can't seem to figure out precisely how to add text files to a zip file, I was able to figure out how to add these text files to a 7zip file which was insanely easy, but a zip file seems to me much more complicated for some reason. I want to return a zip file for user reasons btw.

Here's what I have now: 
(I know the code isn't too clean at the moment, I plan to tackle that after getting the bare functionality down).

```
private ZipOutputStream addThreadDumpsToZipFile(File file, List<Datapoint<ThreadDump>> allThreadDumps, List<Datapoint<String>> allThreadDumpTextFiles) {
  ZipOutputStream threadDumpsZipFile = null;

  try {
      //creat new zip file which accepts input stream
      //TODO missing step: create text files containing each thread dump then add to zip
      threadDumpsZipFile = new ZipFile(new FileOutputStream(file));
      FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
      try {
          //add data to each thread dump entry
          for(int i=0; i<allThreadDumpTextFiles.size();i++) {
              //create file for each thread dump
             File threadDumpFile = new File("thread_dump_"+i+".txt");
             FileUtils.writeStringToFile(threadDumpFile,allThreadDumpTextFiles.get(i).toString());

              //add entry/file to zip file (creates block to add input to)
              ZipEntry threadDumpEntry = new ZipEntry("thread_dump_"+i); //might need to add extension here?
              threadDumpsZipFile.putNextEntry(threadDumpEntry);

              //add the content to this entry
              fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(threadDumpFile);
              byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[(int) threadDumpFile.length()]; //see if this sufficiently returns length of data
              int bytesRead = -1;
              while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {
                  threadDumpsZipFile.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
              }
          }
          threadDumpsZipFile.flush();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          try {
              fileInputStream.close();
          } catch(Exception e) {

          }
      }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return threadDumpsZipFile;
```

}

As you can sort of guess, I have a set of Thread Dumps that I want to add to my zip file and return to the user.

Let me know if you guys need any more info!
PS: There might be some bugs in this question, I just realized with some breakpoints that the threadDumpFile.length() won't really work.

Look forward to your replies!
Thanks,
Arsa

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crack at it. I think you'll want to keep the file extensions when you make your `ZipEntry` objects. See if you can implement the below `createTextFiles()` function; the rest of this works -- I stubbed that method to return a single "test.txt" file with some dummy data to verify.

```
void zip()  
{ 
   try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("yourZipFile.zip");
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        File[] textFiles = createTextFiles(); // should be an easy step

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            addToZipFile(file[i].getName(), zos);
        }
        zos.close();
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

void addToZipFile(String fileName, ZipOutputStream zos) throws Exception {  
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
        fis.close();
    }
```